# Eps to svg, special character not converted

Tags: svg, fonts, ghostscript, inkscape

I'm trying to convert an eps (created with Mathtype) to svg format.
I don't have any problems with math characteres, but I'm unable to get any special characters (aka àâä...)

I have tried on unix and windows, and none of those works.
The font used is Arial, and is installed properly(Default on Windows, manually added in fonts folder in unix)

I have oppened the Arial font in windows font manager and the non working character are in.
They just aren't converted.

Actually, to convert I use Inkscape (with ghostscript) like this :
inkscape -z -f in.eps -l out.svg

Thanks in advance,

Edit :

```
Added in.eps file 

https://pastebin.com/vBtUVy69
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have installed Arial on your Windows box has little to do with the problem.

Does the EPS file include the embedded Arial font ? If not then you are dependent on font substitution. You should probably post a sample EPS file so that we can look at it.

My guess is that the Arial font is not embedded, so Ghostscript substittues Helvetica, and the Helvetica font doesn't have those glyphs, or they are not encoded at the character codes which the EPS file thinks they are.

[EDIT]

The EPS comments say DocumentNeededFonts: Arial-BoldMT", so the EPS does not include the font and you get font substitution.

I can't tell you immediately why the SVG says Arial. I can guess, but in the absence of a complete description as to how you are producing the SVG I can't (obviously) be sure.

Now... **if** the conversion path uses Ghostscript's pdfwrite device to create a PDF file from the EPS, and that PDF file is then somehow converted to Inkscape's internal format (or directly to SVG using something other than Ghostscript) then what is happening is that Ghostscript is substituting Helvetica for the missing Arial-BoldMT and when it produces the PDF file it embeds the Helvetica font, but **calls** it Arial-BoldMT (or whatever). That's a consequence of the font substitution, the font that gets substituted gets renamed to the expected name.

I think you can avoid that by setting `-dEmbedAllFonts` to false, though I haven't tested it. Even if you do, all that happens is that the PDF file then doesn't have the font, just the same as the EPS file. So the SVG creation will (presumably) have to use a substitute font instead. All you do is shove the problem further down.

The correct answer to this is 'always embed fonts'.

You can also make the Arial-BoldMT font available to Ghostscript by editing its fontmap.GS file in ghostpdl/Resource/Init for builds where the resources are not built into a ROM file system. For builds which do use a ROM file system (eg Windows) you must pick up a copy of the Resources (from the Ghostscript Git repository), modify the fontmap.GS file and then tell Ghostscript to use the modified resources by pointing to it with the `-I` switch.

This is still a hack, because its a TrueType font being used as a replacement for a PostScript font, so there's a certain amount of guesswork going on inside Ghostscript, but it usually works well enough, YMMV.

Comment: I've added in.eps.
Effectively, it seem's that Arial font isn't embed.
But If Helvetica is used as replacement, why in svg result, font is set to arial?

Comment: Edited my answer, comment is too long.